# Play a sound on touch?

Tags: android

I was working on a simple bubblewrap app in order to learn the android framework, and was wondering how I could play the 'pop' sound clip every time the user touches a bubble.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `SoundPool` combined with an `OnTouchListener`.
In your `onTouch(..)` method you would simply do a `SoundPool.play(YOURAUDIOFILE, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);`

Gl hf

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a cop out to just link to someone else's explanation, but I had to do the exact same thing, and here's the tutorial I used: http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-2,695.html

Comment: This link leads to completely out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use MedaiPlayer as following inside onTouchListener:

```
  mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(mContext,
                        Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.YourFileName));
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not setup media player for ringtone");
                mPlayer = null;
                return;
            }
            mPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mPlayer.start();
```