# How to fetch images from drive or SD card and store in array

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a presentation type app for my multimedia project. How  can I let the user select images from SD card or drive (for testing), and load in an array so that I can dynamically show these images in image viewer in `postDelay()` method. Also, how I can play sound according to user choice like images?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog) is the first part to select a file from drive.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187975/how-to-create-bitmap-from-sdcard-images-in-android) is how to load the selected image.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770618/play-a-sound-on-touch) is how to play sound.

Comment: These links aren't useful i checked them already like first link is just about txt files

Comment: I have already used the first answer as a method to browse images. If you change the FTYPE file filter to image extensions (or simply omit it) then it is OK.